# How to create GPG keys via shell script for root user?

Tags: ssh, gnupg

For an application I'm making I have to use GPG in a root process on machine #1. On some other machine (#2) I want to run a shell script, that creates keys (secret and public) in GPG for user root on machine #1.

First I create a file, key.scr, where I define characteristics for the new key.

When I run

```
gpg --batch --gen-key /hdd/myfolder/key.scr"
```

via ssh for user , a perfect key-pair is created and saved in /home//.gnupg

But my goal is to create keys for the user root, who must use these keys in some crontab-job.

I tried the following:

```
echo "<MyPassword>" | sudo -S gpg --batch --gen-key /hdd/myfolder/key.scr
```

and

```
sudo -u root gpg --batch --gen-key /hdd/myfolder/key.scr
```

I also placed

```
gpg --batch --gen-key /hdd/myfolder/key.scr
```

in a shell command file , and ran

```
sudo <BatchFile>
```

but I only messed up the .gnupg folder for  (the access rights for several files in this folder are changed to root - root, so they are not readable any longer by .

So, what is the proper way to create via ssh GPG keys which can be used by user root, while root access is not possible via ssh?

Comment: It seems the environment variables are somewhat messed up with `sudo` on your machine. Try `sudo su -` to _really_  switch into root context, and create keys again. By the way: Stack Overflow considers everything in brackets not escaped as code as HTML, so some parts of your post are pretty much garbled. Have a look at the preview when posting to verify against such issues.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.